# Existing Abstract Class Now Needs Dynamic API Keys

Tags: php, api, abstract-class

I have, within a SaaS app, an abstract class with ~12 extensions totaling ~60 methods, thus making this abstraction quite valuable.

However, these methods must now reference client-specific and db-housed API Keys, as we aim to integrate with a particular CRM that requires this dynamic data. This makes instances ideal, but at the cost of the abstraction.

No longer can we statically store these keys for use with user sessions and crons.

Without doing something as seemingly sloppy as manually setting server variables (notice my desperation), how would you architect this?

P.S. Before something is said, I've referenced SO enough to appreciate the value of code examples, but didn't see an application here.

Thank you.